# Discord.js: message.guild.channels.cache.filter

Tags: javascript, discord.js, mute

Im trying to make a mute command for my discord bot but im having trouble filtering the channels to set send messages and add reactions to false, the role is being created but the channels aren't being filtered.
code:

```
let muterole = message.guild.roles.create({
                name: 'muted',
                color: 'BLUE',
                reason: 'For Muted People',
              })
            message.guild.channels.cache.filter(m => m.type === 'text').forEach(async (channel, id) => {
                await channel.createOverwrite(muterole, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                    ADD_REACTIONS: false
                })
            });
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?